# efficient remove of row from dataset linked to SQL database

Tags: c#, dataset

**Hello everone**
I'm removing rows from a dataset. All rows that I want to delete have in common that the column have the same value, hence the `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.stock == key)` which is an int by the way.

```
 public bool RemoveStock(string tickerName) {       
        bool couldBeRemoved = false;
        int key = this.getKeyFromtickerName(tickerName);
        stockDataSet.ListingRow found = 
            listingDataTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.stock == key);

        while (found != null) {
            listingDataTable.RemoveListingRow(found);     
            found = listingDataTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.stock == key);
        }

        listingTa.Update(listingDataTable);
        listingDataTable.AcceptChanges();
        return couldBeRemoved;
    }
```

**edit** The time is spent in the loop. I assume that the function `.FirstOrDefault` starts from the beginning of the dataset and I have around 2.5 milion rows, if I remember correctly. **end edit**

The function works, but painfully slow. It take an order of 10 - 15 minutes to remove 7000 rows. It has to be a better way but how?

Best regards
Gorgen

Comment: Did you check whether the time is spent in AcceptChanges or in your loop?

Comment: it is the loop that is taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating all the records from the start with your while loop. You could just iterate it once to find the records that need to be removed and then you can remove them in a loop like so:

```
var itemsToBeRemoved = listingDataTable.Where(x=>x.stock == key).ToList();
foreach (var item in itemsToBeRemoved) 
              listingDataTable.RemoveListingRow(item);
```

Comment: when I used an IEnumerable the collection were invalidated. But not when made to a List? Apperently Anyway, worked like a charm what I can see, many thanks.